# What does the IMS kill streak do?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I've unlocked the IMS kill streak on multiplayer several times now.

However, I'm unsure what it actually does?

Comment: The IMS rules. In domination, place it right on the flag after you capture it, pure gold for sucka whos run in thinking it's an unguarded flag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the [Intelligent Munitions System](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Intelligent_Munitions_System) is...

> [...] an anti-personnel system similar to the Bouncing Betty. [...] that fires an explosive shell vertically, which in turn then shoots an explosive down at enemies. It can deploy a total of **four explosive charges** before self destructing.

Comment: So if an enemy comes near my IMS, it will blow them up?

Comment: yes, thats it - some kind of mixture between bouncing betty and sentry gun.

Comment: Sweet, cheers @oezi

Comment: It is like a claymore, only it has 4 explosion slots and a bit lower triggering threshold.

Comment: These things are impossible to run away from. If you hear the high pitched sound, it's already too late. Your best bet is to remember the location and toss in an EMP grenade next time

Comment: With the Stalker Pro perk, you are given extra time to sprint past an IMS and get around a corner. If you are still in LOS to the IMS it will still kill you, but walls stop the explosion.

Comment: @Earlz Unless you are using stalker pro perk which allows for faster movement while aiming and very delayed reaction time (about 5 seconds) to IMS, claymore and bouncing betty.

Answer (score 2):

The IMS will also destroy small vehicles such as the recon drone and assault tank. Might even blow up other IMS/turrets if you can place it close enough.